# Spring boot actuator in multiple services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have spring boot actuator which collects metrics in grafana for an existing service (`ServiceA`). I want to add another different service to my system (`ServiceB`) and be able to distinguish the metrics from both these services. I have added custom tags to `http.server.requests`, but what about other metrics which have colliding names? like `process.uptime`? How do I differentiate this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean Grafana collects metrics from Spring Boot Actuator? How are these metrics scraped, through Prometheus?

Comment: I have `micrometer-registry-influx` which pushes the metrics to influxdb. Grafana shows the metrics from this influxdb